GLEW vs WinAPI, windows size and click coordinates problem
I have some discrepancies when I use different windowing APIs. When I create window with WinAPI it is 1.5 times larger than the window created by GLFW. Documentation for both says that width and height are taken in screen coordinates.
I have taken a look into monitor settings, and it shows Scale 150%, that corresponds to 1.5 times discrepance:

To solve it, I used glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SCALE_TO_MONITOR, GLFW_TRUE); in GLFW. It solved the Window size problem, but now in GLFW the mouse click coordinates provided on callbacks are 1.5 times bigger. So, the problem is the 150% discrepancy on mouse coordinates between GLFW and WinAPI. The GLFW still returns coordinates in pixels, instead of screen coordinates.
Here is code for GLFW
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, 
        [](GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int modsd) 
        {
            if (action == GLFW_RELEASE)
            {
                double xpos, ypos;
                glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);
                cout << "release x:"<<xpos<<" y:"<< ypos << endl;
            }
        }
    );

And here is the code for WinAPI (ATL)
    LRESULT OnLButtonUp(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        using std::cout;
        using std::endl;
        POINT c{ GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
        cout<< c<< endl;

        InvalidateRect(0, false);
        return 0;
    }

There are complete listings for GLFW and WinAPI:
// GLFW
#include <GL/glew.h> // Take care: GLEW should be included before GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int width = 1280, height = 720;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SCALE_TO_MONITOR, GLFW_TRUE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        cerr << "GLEW Error: " << glewGetErrorString(err) << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //init gl programs

    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, 
        [](GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int modsd) 
        {
            if (action == GLFW_RELEASE)
            {
                double xpos, ypos;
                glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);
                cout << "release x:"<<xpos<<" y:"<< ypos << endl;
            }
        }
    );
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, 
        [](GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
        {
            if (action == GLFW_PRESS && key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE)
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
        }
    );

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        ///draw some opengl
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

//WinAPI
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Windowsx.h>

#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlwin.h>

#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, POINT pt)
{
    os << "{x:" << pt.x << "y:" << pt.y << "}";
    return os;
}
int glProgramInit()
{
 // init opengl program here
}

class CMyWindow : public CWindowImpl<CMyWindow>
{
public:

    CMyWindow() {}
    virtual ~CMyWindow() {}

    /////////////////////////// Message Handlers /////////////////////////////////

    LRESULT OnPaint(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        HDC hdc;
        //display();
        SwapBuffers(hdc = this->GetWindowDC());
        ReleaseDC(hdc);
        return 0;
    }
    LRESULT OnDestroy(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        //glProgramDestroy();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    HGLRC initOpenGL(HDC hdc)
    {
        using std::cerr;
        using std::endl;
        PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd =
        {
            sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), 1,
            PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,    //Flags
            PFD_TYPE_RGBA,        // The kind of framebuffer. RGBA or palette.
            32,                   // Colordepth of the framebuffer.
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            24,                   // Number of bits for the depthbuffer
            8,                    // Number of bits for the stencilbuffer
            0,                    // Number of Aux buffers in the framebuffer.
            PFD_MAIN_PLANE, 0, 0, 0, 0
        };

        int  newPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd);
        SetPixelFormat(hdc, newPixelFormat, &pfd);

        HGLRC hglrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
        wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hglrc);

        GLenum err = glewInit();
        if (GLEW_OK != err)
        {
            cerr << "GLEW Error: " << glewGetErrorString(err) << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        return hglrc;
    }
    LRESULT OnCreate(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        RECT rc = CWindow::rcDefault;
        this->GetWindowRect(&rc);
        rc.right  = rc.left + width;
        rc.bottom = rc.top  + height;
        this->SetWindowPos(HWND_TOP, &rc, SWP_NOZORDER);

        HDC hdc;
        this->initOpenGL(hdc = this->GetWindowDC());
        ReleaseDC(hdc);

        glProgramInit();
        return 0;
    }
    LRESULT OnLButtonUp(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        using std::cout;
        using std::endl;
        POINT c{ GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
        cout<< c<< endl;

        InvalidateRect(0, false);
        return 0;
    }

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMyWindow)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_DESTROY,   OnDestroy)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_PAINT,     OnPaint)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CREATE,    OnCreate)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_LBUTTONUP, OnLButtonUp)
    END_MSG_MAP()
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CMyWindow cwnd;

    HWND hWnd = cwnd.Create(NULL, CWindow::rcDefault, L"Hello", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
    cwnd.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}


Don't know, but maybe there's something like this available: https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1RenderTarget.php#a2d3e9d7c4a1f5ea7e52b06f53e3011f9 ?

Some functions use logical coordinates (screen coordinates), such as GetCursorPos and GetWindowRect, while others use physical coordinates (in pixels), such as BitBlt, and the same seems to be true for GLFW. It can be difficult to know which API calls will return virtualized values based on the thread context; this information is not currently sufficiently documented by Microsoft.
When the scale is 100% (96 DPI) or your application is declared as DPI-aware, logical coordinates and physical coordinates are exactly the same. When the scale is 150% (144 DPI) and the application is not declared as DPI-aware, Windows will virtualize the answer given to the application as if the screen were in 96 DPI units. For example, using GetWindowRect on the DesktopWindow to get the screen size, you will get a width of 2560/1.5=1707 and a height of 1440/1.5=960, and GetCursorPos will also operate in these coordinates.
The solution is to declare your application as DPI-aware, This will solve the problem of inconsistency between logical coordinates and physical coordinates. Or, convert the necessary coordinates yourself using LogicalToPhysicalPointForPerMonitorDPI and PhysicalToLogicalPointForPerMonitorDPI.
Also see:
High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows
PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS enumeration

I didn't ignore your answer, but I still don't understand it. Could you please more detailly explain, how can I get the scale which is 150% (see screenshot)?
